# How to store images in Google BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to store product images in google bigquery database so that i can display these images in my reports.

Is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 3):

You can store binary data in BigQuery by base64-encoding it and storing it as a string.

That said, make sure you consider the caveats in Incognito's answer. Storing images in BigQuery may not be the most efficient use of your query dollar, since you'll pay to query the entire column, which will likely contain a large amount of data and will therefore make your query much more expensive. You might consider [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/products/cloud-storage/) or [Google Cloud Datastore](https://developers.google.com/datastore/) as better alternatives for storing binary data for direct lookup.

Comment: This is way it should be done. Encode the image to a string and store it in bigquery.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think storing images is possible in Google Storage to be processed by Google BigQuery.

Also, as per the official documentation available for Google BigQuery, BigQuery supports **CSV** and **JSON** data formats and [the supported data types can include](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/preparing-data-for-bigquery#datatypes):

> **Data types**
>
> Your data can include strings, integers, floats, booleans,
>   nested/repeated records and timestamps

Also, since BigQuery is for analyzing huge **datasets**, why would you store anything other than **data** which you don't want to process and harness for gathering more information. Plus, you also pay for **storage** and storing images obviously takes a lot of space on the server, so you would cut on that too, to save costs.